# Calculating Covariance with Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I am trying to figure out how to calculate covariance with the Python Numpy function cov.  When I pass it two one-dimentional arrays, I get back a 2x2 matrix of results.  I don't know what to do with that.  I'm not great at statistics, but I believe covariance in such a situation should be a single number.  [This](http://i.investopedia.com/inv/articles/site/Proper%20Covariance.gif) is what I am looking for.  I wrote my own:

```
def cov(a, b):

    if len(a) != len(b):
        return

    a_mean = np.mean(a)
    b_mean = np.mean(b)

    sum = 0

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        sum += ((a[i] - a_mean) * (b[i] - b_mean))

    return sum/(len(a)-1)
```

That works, but I figure the Numpy version is much more efficient, if I could figure out how to use it.

Does anybody know how to make the Numpy cov function perform like the one I wrote?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Minor remark, but you could take advantage of numpy for computing the sum:

`sum = ((a - a_mean) * (b - b-mean)).sum()`

Comment: Why do you return `sum/(len(a)-1)`? Shouldn’t it be `sum/(len(a))`? Subtracting 1 from the length is a mistake

Comment: @Connor Covariance of a sample is described by a formula with N-1 in the denominator; for a population, it is described by N in the denominator. So it really depends on what is being calculated.

Comment: Yep you are correct

Answer (score 143, accepted):

When `a` and `b` are 1-dimensional sequences, `numpy.cov(a,b)[0][1]` is equivalent to your `cov(a,b)`.

The 2x2 array returned by `np.cov(a,b)` has elements equal to

```
cov(a,a)  cov(a,b)

cov(a,b)  cov(b,b)
```

(where, again, `cov` is the function you defined above.)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I wish the documentation had explained it that well.  That works perfectly.  Once I had my own working function, I should have compared the result to the numpy.cov function and I'd probably have figured that out.

I'd vote-up if I could, but I'm new and apparently can't.

Comment: This is incorrect: the `numpy.cov` defaults to calculating the *sample* covariance.  The next answer explains it.  In particular this should say `numpy.cov(a,b, bias=True)[0][1]`

Comment: @javadba: Take a look at the OP's code. He is dividing by `(len(a)-1)` so his `cov` function is computing sample covariance. Therefore, my answer is correct..

Comment: ah ok. But you should add a note to that effect in your answer. I looked at your answer in isolation- and doubtful I were the only one to have done so.

Comment: wouldn't cov(a,a) be... zero?  And cov(a,b) = cov(b,a)?  What is the point of returning 4 arrays?

Comment: @johnktejik: [`cov(a,a) = var(a)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties). In general, the variance, `var(a)`, is not zero.

Answer (score 36):

Thanks to unutbu for the explanation. By default numpy.cov calculates the sample covariance. To obtain the population covariance you can specify normalisation by the total N samples like this:

```
numpy.cov(a, b, bias=True)[0][1]
```

or like this:

```
numpy.cov(a, b, ddof=0)[0][1]
```

Comment: **This** is the correct answer, not the accepted one - which omits the `bias=True`

Comment: Turns out the accepted answer does work: but it does not include mention of the bias adjustment - which is buried in the OP. So this answer info is helpful.

Comment: @ Lerner Zhang. Subtracting n_samples by one provides an unbiased estimator of the population covariance. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator

Comment: @Osian when you say "thanks to ubuntu" if that means you have a reference/source to cite please do so.  Otherwise what does it mean?

Comment: @brethvoice I was referencing the accepted answer provided by unutbu (see above). Although the accepted answer is correct, it does not discuss the important distinction between calculating the sample & population covariance.

Comment: I did not realize there was a user named @unutbu (I also thought it was Ubuntu).  That was the main source of my confusion; I thought you were talking about the Ubuntu user's manual or something: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-manual

Comment: So, by using numpy.cov, we have four times more calculations than necessary? We calculate cov(a,a), cov(a,b), cov(b,a) and cov(b,b), and we need only cov(a,b).

Answer (score 10):

Note that starting in `Python 3.10`, one can obtain the covariance directly from the standard library.

Using [`statistics.covariance`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#statistics.covariance) which is a measure (the number you're looking for) of the joint variability of two inputs:

```
from statistics import covariance

# x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
covariance(x, y)
# 0.75
```

Comment: Nice avoidance of numpy.

Comment: Hopefully statistics will include online versions too soon. In the meantime, https://github.com/microprediction/precise