# What is the difference between MATLAB/Octave corr and Python numpy.correlate?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave, correlation

I am trying to port a MATLAB/Octave program to Python using NumPy 1.8.0 and Python 2.7.3.  I've used [this reference](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) as help in converting MATLAB functions to NumPy methods with great success, until I get to the point where I want to compute the correlation between two matrices.

The first matrix is 40000x25 floats, the second matrix is 40000x1 ints.  In Octave I use the statement `corr(a,b)` and get a 25x1 matrix of floats.  Trying the corresponding method in NumPy (`numpy.correlate(a,b)`) produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_1a9aa5a_20130415-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 751, in correlate
  return multiarray.correlate2(a,v,mode)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I can get it to work if I change the code to calculate a correlation for each column of `a`, like so:

```
for i in range(25):
    c2[i] = numpy.correlate(a[:,i], b)
```

However, the values in the `c2` array are different than the output from Octave. Octave returns a 25x1 matrix of floats all less than 1.  The values I get from NumPy are floats between -270 and 900.

I have tried to understand what the two algorithms are doing under the hood but have failed miserably.  Can someone point out my logic failure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that there exists a `numpy.corrcoef` which computes the correlation coefficients, as desired. However, its interface is different from the Octave/Matlab `corr`.

First of all, by default, the function treats rows as variables, with the columns being observations. To mimic the behavior of Octave/Matlab, you can pass a flag which reverses this.

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317971/716118), the `numpy.cov` function (which `corrcoef` uses internally, I assume) returns a 2x2 matrix, each of which contain a specific covariance:

```
cov(a,a)  cov(a,b)

cov(a,b)  cov(b,b)
```

As he points out, the `[0][1]` element is what you'd want for `cov(a,b)`. Thus, perhaps something like this will work:

```
for i in range(25):
    c2[i] = numpy.corrcoef(a[:,i], b, rowvar=0)[0][1]
```

---

For reference, here are some excerpts of the two functions that you had tried. It seems to be that they perform completely different things.

Octave:

> — Function File: corr (x, y)
>
> Compute matrix of correlation coefficients.
>
> If each row of x and y is an observation and each column is a
>   variable, then the (i, j)-th entry of corr (x, y) is the correlation
>   between the i-th variable in x and the j-th variable in y.
>
> ```
>       corr (x,y) = cov (x,y) / (std (x) * std (y))
> ```
>
> If called with one argument, compute corr (x, x), the correlation between the columns
>   of x.

And Numpy:

> numpy.correlate(a, v, mode='valid', old_behavior=False)[source]
>
> Cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences.
>
> This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal
>   processing texts:
>
> ```
> z[k] = sum_n a[n] * conj(v[n+k])
> ```
>
> with a and v sequences being zero-padded where necessary and conj being the conjugate.

Comment: I have tried that but `numpy.cov(a,b)` returns a 2x2 array of floats and I don't know how that relates to the correlation.

Comment: or try to simply get [Pearson's r](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.12.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)

Comment: or [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)

Comment: @Rasman - I have tried `corrcoef`, but it also returns a 2x2 array that I don't know what to do with.  I just tried `pearsonsr` and have the same questions.  While these values look much better than what I'm getting from `correlate`, I'm still not getting the same answers as the octave function.  Should I expect to?

Comment: @Crystal: I think I may have found what the 2x2 array is all about. I've edited my answer to give a possible solution.

Comment: @voithos: thanks.  I'm still not getting the same values as the octave output, but it's looking much better.

Comment: @Crystal: Do you have any (small) example values that you could show?

Comment: @voithos: I just ran the full program.  While the numbers don't match perfectly, the result looks ok - I'm getting a spike on my plot at the value I expect to.  I'll try to study this to understand a bit more of what's really going on, but I'm marking this answered.  Thanks!

Comment: @Crystal: If you figure this out, I'd encourage you to write up an answer yourself so that others may benefit in the future.

Comment: @voithos: Just realized my mistake.  I had a one-off error in my expected value (forgot that matlab/octave starts at 1).  Once I made that correction, your solution gives me correlation values nearly identical to octave.  And the plot looks exactly the same.  THANKS!