# np.cov giving unexpected number of values

Tags: python, numpy, covariance-matrix

When using `np.cov` command on a random dataset of 10 values, I'm getting a `10x10` array as the answer. I think my data is not formatted correctly, but I'm not sure.

```
np.random.seed(1)
rho = 0.2
sigma = 1
cov = (sigma**2)*[[1,rho],[rho,1]]
mean1 = (0,0)
x1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov, (10))
mean1 = np.mean(x1)
cov1 = np.cov(x1)
print(cov1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behavior—[`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) returns a covariance matrix.

In particular, it takes each row of the input as a variable, with the columns representing different values of those variables. To reverse this behavior, pass `rowvar=False`.

In particular, if you have two variables represented as two columns of a matrix, you can use `np.cov(data, rowvar=False)` (or `np.cov(data.T)`) to get a 2 by 2 covariance matrix, in which the elements at `cov[0,1]` and `cov[1,0]` will be the covariance between the two variables.

This is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317971).