# Covariance between two 3D arrays in python

Tags: python, statistics

`A = [time, x, y];` , `B = [time, x, y]`
How can I find the covariance between A and B on time axis so that I can plot the the covariance on x, y plane?

Answer (score 0):

This gives 2d array with size (x,y) that can be plotted on x,y dimensional space

`for i in range (0, len(x)):
    for j in range (0, len(y)):
        cov[j,i] = numpy.cov(A[:,j,i],B[:,j,i])[0,1]`

 It's funny how nump.cov operates. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317822/calculating-covariance-with-python-and-numpy) will shed some lights too.